# ReactJS: Updated filled forms and return to initial state after cancel

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, antd

I'm currently wondering how to go back to the form's initial state after cancel.

Here is the scenario:

1. I have a user information form that I need to update.
2. In the form, I can already see my data.
3. I changed a value in one of the fields.
4. After changing the value, I realized I do not want to update it yet so I click cancel.

When I click on Cancel, it should go back to the original data.

My current situation is that when I click on cancel, I am using resetFields(); function which clears all the input fields.

```
const cancel = () => {
     form.resetFields()
    }
```

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Is it not working? Are you managing your values in state or are they uncontrolled inputs?

Comment: @BrianThompson they are in state

Comment: You need to save the initial state, on cancel not `.resetFields()` but use `.setFields({})`

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the initial state, on cancel not `.resetFields()` but use `.setFields({})` to reset.

Read docs about [form instance](https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance)

Here example:

```
form.setFields({ ...state })
```

Initial state save in this format:

```
{
   firstInput: {
     value: 'value', errors: []
   },
   secondInput: {
     value: 'value', errors: []
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it's throwing an error form.setFields is not a function

Comment: @danedelions_swift you wrapped component? `export default Form.create({ name: 'youForm' })(Form)` ?

Comment: create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) example of you form